# Mysql bind_param() error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
require_once'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['subscribe'])){
  $email=$_POST['email'];

  //check the email if it is already subscribed or not
  if(strlen($email)>3){             
    $stmt=$mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->field_count > 0){ // if not then add
      unset($mysql); unset($stmt);
      $mysql=new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);     
      $stmt=$mysql->prepare('INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES (?)');
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->affected_rows>0){
        echo "subscribed";
      }
    } else { //else is there
      echo "Already there";
    }
  } else echo "empty string";
}
?>
```

If I delete the line `unset($mysql); unset($stmt);` then it causes a fatal error: `Bind_param Non-Object Error`. But if I unset and then redefine the object then works fine. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Why are you reconnecting? Lose the unset and redefine. If it fails, var_dump the $mysql object.

Comment: What line is throwing the fatal?

Comment: how you using if($stmt->field_count > 0) which means a record already exists it should be if($stmt->field_count == 0)

Comment: right. Thanks for that. That was a mistake. But is not the ans what I need to know.

Comment: The $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); line after unset($mysql); unset($stmt); is throuing error

Comment: @Farkie: Reconnecting cause if I do not unset and redo then causes the error

Comment: If you remove 'unset($mysql); unset($stmt);
      $mysql=new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);'

everything should work as normal.. not sure why it wouldn't. I assume $mysql is set in config.php in your example code?

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: this is untested. However, I thought it was important to demonstrate how to write this in a cleaner manner. In particular, break up your intent into specific functions, each of which do one thing and return the result. This will help keep your code from getting confusing and make it easier to test each chunk on it's own.

```
require_once'config.php';

//It is always good to declare stuff like this in a central place
//That way they're easy to change, and you change it everywhere you have that express intent
$SQL_FIND_SUBSCRIPTION = "SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE email=?";
$SQL_NEW_SUBSCRIPTION = "INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES (?)";

//Functions make testing easy!
static function attemptSubscription($postValues, &$returnMsg) {
  if (   isset($postValues['subscribe']) 
      && isset($postValues['email']) //be sure to validate both!

  {
    if (isValidEmail($postValues['email'])) {
      subscribe($email);//this syntax may be off.

    } else {
      $returnMsg = "A valid email address must be provided.";
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    $returnMsg = "No subscription was attempted.";
    return false;
  }
}


//Returns true if the passed parameter is a valid email
static function isValidEmail($email) {
  //left as an exercise for the reader. 
}

//Assumes a valid email address is being passed
static function subscribe($email, &$returnMsg) {
  global $mysql; //sadly, this is the cleanest way possible without using a class.
  $stmt=$mysql->prepare($SQL_FIND_SUBSCRIPTION);
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result(); // This lets you reuse stmt

  if($stmt->field_count > 0){ 
    //Subscription already exists
    $returnMsg = "This subscription already exists.";
    return true;
  } else { 
    //Subscription must be added
    return addNewSubscription($email, $returnMsg);
  }
}

static function addNewSubscription($email, &$returnMsg) {
  global $mysql; // :(
  $stmt=$mysql->prepare($SQL_NEW_SUBSCRIPTION);
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();

  if($stmt->affected_rows>0){
    $returnMsg = "New subscription successful!";
    return true;
  } else {
    $returnMsg = "New subscription failed.";//you can add more info here if you want
    return false;
  }

  $stmt->close();
}

//now actually execute
$resultMsg = "";
if (attemptSubscription($_POST, $resultMsg)) {
  echo "Success! ".$resultMsg;
} else {
  echo "Oh no! Failure! ".$resultMsg;
}



// ?> Note that eliding this will help remove nasty hidden characters from the rendered html
```

Check out [store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) for more.

Using this sort of configuration you can verify that individual commands are working, without relying on first executing the structures they're nested in. In particular, it is vital you verify your second sql query: a non-binding error is often because the column or table cannot be found. However, that said, realize that what the `prepare()` statement does is send a query to the server to be checked for syntax; that query is never resent, but rather stays 'loaded' in the server until you tell it (with another statement) to get rid of it. When you subsequently bind a parameter, that parameter is sent to the server and placed into the available slot (`?`). You can then execute this query many times efficiently, because of this model.

Note that if the query on the server does not have an unbound slot for a new parameter, an attempt to bind it will fail. If the query on the server is attempting to reference non-available variables (such as column name) it will also fail at this step.

It is unclear from your provided details where the exact problem is, but if you write your code in a more clean manner debugging these issues will become much easier: is it that your second sql statement is bad? Is it that you're not properly releasing the server resource from the first statement?

Comment: Thanks for the code. But Actually I wanted a conceptual description why my code sends error if I do not unset.

Comment: @MohaiminusSakib Added more details, but you may not be providing enough information here to solve your problem. Also note that you don't need to unset; that is almost certainly overkill for this situation.